# How can I pass this Javascript code to Typescript? It's from a trivia (API)

Tags: angular, typescript

I am passing an API code on the internet (Open trivia quiz https://opentdb.com/api_config.php).

The following a code that is in html, css, js.

I want to pass that code to Angular, which works with Typescript. I was able to load an array with the questions, but I can't show it in the interface (the question and answers), but now I'm trying to make the startGame function work. I will show it next next to the part that loads the trivia (everything is in js).

I hope you can help me, thank you very much.

**JS**

```
const question = document.getElementById("question");
const choices = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("choice-text"));
const progressText = document.getElementById("progressText");
const scoreText = document.getElementById("score");
const progressBarFull = document.getElementById("progressBarFull");
const loader = document.getElementById("loader");
const game = document.getElementById("game");
let currentQuestion = {};
let acceptingAnswers = false;
let score = 0;
let questionCounter = 0;
let availableQuestions = [];
let questions = [];

var url = localStorage.getItem("urlGame");

  fetch(
    url
    )
    .then(res => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(loadedQuestions => {
      console.log(loadedQuestions.results);
      questions = loadedQuestions.results.map(loadedQuestion => {
        const formattedQuestion = {
          question: loadedQuestion.question
        };

        const answerChoices = [...loadedQuestion.incorrect_answers];
        formattedQuestion.answer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
        answerChoices.splice(
        formattedQuestion.answer - 1,
        0,
        loadedQuestion.correct_answer
        );
        answerChoices.forEach((choice, index) => {
          formattedQuestion["choice" + (index + 1)] = choice;
        });

        return formattedQuestion;
      });

      startGame();
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });

  //CONSTANTS
  const CORRECT_BONUS = 2;
  const MAX_QUESTIONS = 20;
  const INCORRECT_BONUS = -1;

  startGame = () => {
    questionCounter = 0;
    score = 0;
    availableQuestions = [...questions];
    getNewQuestion();
    game.classList.remove("hidden");
    loader.classList.add("hidden");
  };

  getNewQuestion = () => {
    if (availableQuestions.length === 0 || questionCounter >= MAX_QUESTIONS) {
      localStorage.setItem("mostRecentScore", score);
      //go to the end page
      return window.location.assign("/html/end.html");
    }
    questionCounter++;
    progressText.innerText = `Question ${questionCounter}/${MAX_QUESTIONS}`;
    //Update the progress bar
    progressBarFull.style.width = `${(questionCounter / MAX_QUESTIONS) * 100}%`;

    const questionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableQuestions.length);
    currentQuestion = availableQuestions[questionIndex];
    question.innerHTML = currentQuestion.question;

    choices.forEach(choice => {
      const number = choice.dataset["number"];
      choice.innerHTML = currentQuestion["choice" + number];
    });

    availableQuestions.splice(questionIndex, 1);
    acceptingAnswers = true;
  };
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
      <div id="loader"></div>
      <div id="game" class="justify-center flex-column hidden">
          <div id="hud">
          <div id="hud-item">
            <p id="progressText" class="hud-prefix">
              Question
            </p>
            <div id="progressBar">
              <div id="progressBarFull"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="hud-item">
            <p class="hud-prefix">
              Score
            </p>
            <h1 class="hud-main-text" id="score">
              0
            </h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2 id="question"></h2>
        <div class="choice-container">
          <p class="choice-prefix">A</p>
          <p class="choice-text" data-number="1"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="choice-container">
          <p class="choice-prefix">B</p>
          <p class="choice-text" data-number="2"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="choice-container">
          <p class="choice-prefix">C</p>
          <p class="choice-text" data-number="3"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="choice-container">
          <p class="choice-prefix">D</p>
          <p class="choice-text" data-number="4"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**index.components.ts**

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

const url: string = 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=20';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-index',
  templateUrl: './index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index.component.css']
})
export class IndexComponent{

  constructor() { }

  public diff: string;

  public cat: string;

  public typ: string;

  public newUrl: string;

  public setChange() {
    this.newUrl = url + this.cat + this.diff + this.typ;
    localStorage.setItem('urlGame', this.newUrl);
  }
}
```

Comment: is this working for java script

Comment: In javascript it works perfectly

Comment: but this not complete code can  you share your api calling part also

Comment: and also provide what will be the output

Comment: Add the API call through a link

Comment: Everything is in js

Comment: can you also provide urlGame

Comment: Ready, I have that one in ts

Comment: https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10

Comment: The basic one is opentdb.com/api.php?amount=20
But the idea is that it has different categories, difficulties and type of questions (that varies the base url)

Comment: Can we start this in conversation i am still not clean to you trying to display

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: @harkeshkumar I'm sorry for the delay

Comment: are you still having same issue

Comment: @harkeshkumar 
I still can't move on

Comment: can you tell me what time you mostly online

Comment: @harkeshkumar Now I am online (I am from Chile and here is 02:29 am)

Comment: ok no issue we can fix this problem

Comment: can you tell me what output you want in angular

Comment: can you share any screenshot

Comment: @harkeshkumar 
I need to load the API, it consists of different questions (in this case 20) and each question has 4 alternatives with one correct (except if it is true and false that there are two)

Comment: can you also share Url value that you getting from localstorage

Comment: @harkeshkumar 
https://gitlab.com/silvatapialuis/trivia.git

In this link is the app developed in js if you want to see how it works and what it does ... to start it you must install the extensive live server in visual studio code.

Comment: from your code am gettinng such value  can you check and let know its somethink like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-fo2p5m

Comment: url
opentdb.com/api.php?amount=20

Comment: @harkeshkumar 
yes, it's something like that

Comment: @harkeshkumar 
How do I do that in an angular project? where do you work with index.component.ts ... do I have to make a file with the name index.component.js?

Comment: working on it https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qyvvrz

Comment: @harkeshkumar 
thanks, hopefully you can see the work I did in javascript so that the final idea is better understood. For now I will go to rest since it is 4 in the morning here ... Thank you very much for your help

Comment: can you check same link

Comment: @harkeshkumar 
I was seeing it and it just says the wrong answers and not all the answers (incorrect_answers and correct_answer)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/question-answer-game-hkocaa

Comment: sorry i does not what you trying to say

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204106/discussion-between-harkesh-kumar-and-luis-fernando-silva).

Comment: Is your work is done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/question-answer-game-hkocaa)

```
 constructor(private http: HttpClient){

    this.http.get<any>(`https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&difficulty=easy`)
    .subscribe(loadedQuestions=>{
      this.QuestionObject=loadedQuestions.results;
      this.QuestionList=loadedQuestions.results;


      this.questions = loadedQuestions.results.map(loadedQuestion => {
      let formattedQuestion:any={};
      let answerArray:any[]=[];

             //console.log(loadedQuestion);

          answerArray=loadedQuestion.incorrect_answers;
          answerArray.push(loadedQuestion.correct_answer)
          //console.log(this.shuffleAnswer(answerArray))
           formattedQuestion.question=loadedQuestion.question;
           formattedQuestion.answer = this.shuffleAnswer(answerArray);



            return formattedQuestion;
          });

          this.startGame();

        })

      }


      startGame () {

         console.log(this.questions)

        this.questionCounter = 0;
       this.score = 0;
        this.availableQuestions = [...this.questions];
        this.getNewQuestion();
       // this.game.classList.remove("hidden");
       // this.loader.classList.add("hidden");
      };

       getNewQuestion() {

         console.log(this.availableQuestions)
       /*  if (this.availableQuestions.length === 0 || this.questionCounter >= this.MAX_QUESTIONS) {
         // localStorage.setItem("mostRecentScore", score);
          //go to the end page
          return window.location.assign("/html/end.html");
        } */
        this.questionCounter++;
        this.progressText = `Question ${this.questionCounter}/${this.MAX_QUESTIONS}`;
        //Update the progress bar
        this.progressBarFull = `${(this.questionCounter / this.MAX_QUESTIONS) * 100}%`;

        const questionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.availableQuestions.length);
        this.currentQuestion = this.availableQuestions[questionIndex];
        this.question= this.currentQuestion.question;

        let allChoice=this.currentQuestion.answer;

        allChoice.forEach(choice => {
          const number = choice.dataset["number"];
          choice = this.currentQuestion["choice" + number];
        });

        /* this.availableQuestions.splice(questionIndex, 1);
        this.acceptingAnswers = true; */

     console.log(this.question)


      };


      shuffleAnswer(array){ 
        var m = array.length, t, i;

        // While there remain elements to shuffle
        while (m) {
          // Pick a remaining element…
          i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

          // And swap it with the current element.
          t = array[m];
          array[m] = array[i];
          array[i] = t;
        }

        return array;
      }
    }
```

In Html

```
<div class="container">
      <div id="loader"></div>
      <div id="game" class="justify-center flex-column hidden">
          <div id="hud">
          <div id="hud-item">
            <p id="progressText" [innerHTML]="progressText" class="hud-prefix">
              Question
            </p>
            <div id="progressBar">
              <div id="progressBarFull" [innerHTML]="progressBarFull"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="hud-item">
            <p class="hud-prefix">
              Score
            </p>
            <h1 class="hud-main-text" id="score">
              0
            </h1>
          </div>
          <button (click)="getNewQuestion()">Next Question</button>
        </div>
        <h2 id="question"  [innerHTML]="currentQuestion.question" ></h2>
        <div class="choice-container">
          <p class="choice-prefix">A</p>
          <p class="choice-text" [innerHTML]="currentQuestion.answer[0]" data-number="1"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="choice-container">
          <p class="choice-prefix">B</p>
          <p class="choice-text" [innerHTML]="currentQuestion.answer[1]"  data-number="2"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="choice-container">
          <p class="choice-prefix">C</p>
          <p class="choice-text" [innerHTML]="currentQuestion.answer[2]"  data-number="3"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="choice-container">
          <p class="choice-prefix">D</p>
          <p class="choice-text"[innerHTML]="currentQuestion.answer[3]"   data-number="4"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
```